# Can this be a proof of Euler's formula?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.

We know $z\overline{z}=1$.

$$\overline{z}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta=\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)$$

Suppose $z=e^{i\theta}$. If this is true, this satisfies $z\overline{z}=1$.

$$\overline{z}=\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)=e^{-i\theta}$$

$$e^{i\theta}e^{-i\theta}=e^{i\theta-i\theta}=e^0$$

So $z=e^{i\theta}$

$$\boxed{e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}$$

Comment: $z\overline{z}=1$ is true for all complex numbers where  $|z|=1$.  So saying it is true for $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ and for $e^{i\theta}$ does not prove they are equal to each other, but instead that they have the same magnitude of $1$.

Comment: Your 'proof' works for any base, not just $e$. So something is wrong. Can you find what it is?

Comment: I would suggest you use the series definition of $\cos, \sin, \exp$ and then show the equivalence.

Comment: What you've verified is that $\bar{z}$ acts as the multiplicative inverse of $z$. That's a necessary but not sufficient condition: If it failed you'd know Euler's formula was false, but it being true isn't enough to confirm Euler's formula.

Comment: Not getting a contradiction isn't a proof.  It's not getting a contradiction.  If $-2 = 0$ then $10 = 5 + 5 = (5+0) + (5-0) = (5-2) + (5+2) = 3 + 7 = 10$.  Therefore $-2 = 0$.   Not a proof.  And setting $\cos \theta +i\sin \theta = 5^{\frac 23 \theta}$ will give use the same result $1=(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)(\cos -\theta -i\sin \theta) =5^{\frac 23\theta}5^{-\frac 23 \theta} =5^0 = 1$.  Not a proof.

Answer (score 4):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question. You cannot *a priori* suppose to be right, then try to not find a contradiction.

Comment: This says no more than Henry's comment, which came 3 minutes before this answer did.